# Parent __unicode__ in python

Tags: python, inheritance

Suppose I have a class called Animal and a subclass called Dog. How can I access the Animal's **unicode** definition from the Dog class?

```
 class Animal:
      def __unicode__(self):
           return 'animal'

 class Dog(Animal):
      def __unicode__(self):
           return 'this %s is a dog' % (I want to get the Animal's __unicode__ here)
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? (Your code is missing some `def` keywords, by the way.)

Comment: It's python 2. And yeah, sorry about the def.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're implementing old-style classes in Python 2, you can only access the methods of your base class by their qualified names:

```
class Animal:
    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'animal'

class Dog(Animal):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'this %s is a dog' % Animal.__unicode__(self)
```

However, if you modify your base class so it becomes a [new-style class](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-new-style-class), then you can use [super()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

```
class Animal(object):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'animal'

class Dog(Animal):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'this %s is a dog' % super(Dog, self).__unicode__()
```

Note that all classes are new-style classes in Python 3, so `super()` can always be used when running that version.

Comment: You should use for python3: 

'{0}'.format(var)  

Instead of '%s' %(var). 

See: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: @skaran, you're right, but the questioner uses Python 2, not 3. I was only saying that `super()` could be used in all cases if he ever migrates to Python 3.

Comment: Just to expand - in Python 3, `super()` can be called without the arguments as it's implicit. In Python 2.x though, it's explicit so yeah, `super(Dog, self)` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the parent method in a couple of ways:

```
class Dog(Animal):
      def __unicode__(self):
           return 'this %s is a dog' % Animal.__unicode__(self)

class Dog(Animal):
     def __unicode__(self):
           return 'this %s is a dog' % super(Dog, self).__unicode__()
```

Note: In order to use super the parent class has to be a new style class. The second method will fail if used with an old style class like the one defined in the questions.

Comment: It's best when possible to check the code before you post. If you actually try your second suggestion, with the OPs definition of `Animal` running on Python 2 you get `TypeError: must be type, not classobj`

Comment: @Duncan Thank you pointing out the issue. I did not observe that the Animal is an old style class.